# how to insert a line break after every second loop in t-sql stuff function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation

how can i insert a CHAR(10) after every second loop in t-sql stuff function in my query

```
  SELECT  STUFF(
                (
                    SELECT  ', ' + new_name 
                   FROM new_subcatagories
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
```

so the result should by

record1,record2,

record3,record4

Comment: Side note: The above isn't "looping", it's a set based solution. A loop/iterative solution would involve a `WHILE` or an rCTE; which in SQL would be significantly less performant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` expression to see if the value of `ROW_NUMBER` is divisible by `2`, and if not then add a carriage return and line break:

```sql
SELECT STUFF((SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by new_nam) % 2 = 1 THEN CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) ELSE '' END + ', ' + new_nam
              FROM new_subcatagories
              ORDER BY new_nam
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 4, '');
```

Comment: hi larnu, thanks for your help,sorry i am very new to sql ,its working fine for my first query but i want now to use it for a other query where i need to distinct it, because its can be in my case multiple records with the same name,  and its not working in this case here is the query    
        STUFF((
  SELECT distinct CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by   new_maincatgoriesname) % 2 = 1 THEN CHAR(10) ELSE ',' END +   new_maincatgoriesname
  FROM new_subcatagories
     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')